# Get option of multiple activities from phone launcher?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-developer-api, android-native-library

hi see the picture below

[image]

when long press on chrome app icon then I get a quick option to go incognito and open new tab

so how can I do this with my own app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are app shortcuts. Read here on static and dynamic shortcuts, implementation and best practices. [App ShortCuts Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts)